# Graceful Shutdown/Stop RabbitMQ Consumer with Spring Cloud

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

**Edited Question**

I have a spring-boot application running `Spring Boot 2.1` and `Spring Cloud Finley.M2`. The application is integrated with `RabbitMQ` and consumes messages sent by other services towards it. The integration with RabbitMQ has been achieved using Spring Cloud's `@StreamLinster` and `@EnableBinding` abstractions as shown below:

```
@EnableBinding(CustomChannels.class)
public class IncomingChannelHandler {

@StreamListener("inboundChannel")
public void handleIncoming(String incoming) {
    final IncomingActionDTO dto = gson.fromJson(incoming, IncomingActionDTO.class);

    handleIncoming(dto);

  }
}
```

My goal is to be able to stop and start being a consumer of a rabbitMQ queue programmatically.

I tried the solution with the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` but the result was not what I needed, because the stop kept me as a consumer in the queue. I also tried to stop it through lifecycle which did not work either.

Is there a way to inform the queue to stop consider you a consumer until the application registers again as a one?

Comment: When you say `restart the application` are you implying graceful shut down or some kind fo CTRL+C? Also, I am not sure I understand what handler you are talking about.

Comment: @loannis are u expecting that application should not shut down till it process the consumed messages

Comment: you can use dead letter queue mechanism here , and @preDestroy to add non processed notification to send it to Dead letter queue.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Yes gracefully, for an update for example. The handler is another class I have that processes the information consumed from the queue, what it does is irrelevant to the issue that is why I didn't give more information about it.

Comment: @MandarDharurkar Yes ideally it will stop consuming from the queue, the service that manipulates the information from the queue has a manual graceful shutdown. I thought about the preDestroy, the issue is that the listener may stop after the service so it will still consume from the queue which will eventually be lost.

Comment: In that case Dead Letter Queue is solution for you . whenever you receive a notification add it first to dead letter queue , once you consume and process it , remove it from Dead letter queue. this way even if it is consumed and not processed , it can be processed after restart